# Test REST Webservice created with Jhipster (yo jhipster:server)

Tags: jwt, jhipster, postman

a)How may I deal with Jhipster user management and JWT authentication for the basic default application without Angular Interface? (I will use Postman, for example, for testing.)

b)What is the url for swagger UI? Is It available in this Production profile?

c)Do I need to configure email to handle user management?

(I searched a lot in Jhipster webside but did not find a manual explaining how to do it. If someone can point i will be thakfull.)

d)Details:

I created a REST Webservice using Jhipster, without the client side, using:

yo jhipster:server

I decided to use a Monolithic architecture, with Postgres Database, and JWT authetication.

I am using docker and docker-compose. I built the application doing:

./mvnw package -Pprod docker:build

I run the application doing:

docker-compose -f ~/jhipster/src/main/docker/app.yml up

My app is running. For example if I go to

localhost:8080/api/profile-info

I have this as response:

{"activeProfiles":["prod","swagger"],"ribbonEnv":null}

I decided to use Monolithic architecture, because I did not want to deal with Gateway and Registry.

I tried, using Postman to make a POST Http to:

http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate

Using basic athentication: username: admin
password: admin

How should i send those parameters, as JSON?

I have as response:

{
  "message": "error.internalServerError",
  "description": "Internal server error",
  "fieldErrors": null
}

How should i use the jwtSecretKey avilable in file .yo-rc.jon

I expected to have a reponse as described in https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

try run app using yarn start and, run spring-boot from you IDE, this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. 
I found swagger JASON docs in:

localhost:8080/v2/api-docs/

Then i used swagger online editor to view the Docs and followed instructions there. I used Postman to POST to:

localhost:8080/api/authenticate

In body:

{
  "password": "admin",
  "username": "admin"
}

headers:

Content-Type:application/json
Accept:*/* Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache

I received a JSON with id_token